# PHP - Getting the filepath of the file after uploading to server

Tags: php, json, extjs

Good day. I am uploading an image file to my php server. I am successfully uploading the file to a folder. What I want to do now is as I assemble my JSON response, I want to get the new file path of the file so I would know where it is programatically.

Here is my php code so far:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    if (
        !isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'])
    ) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'status' => "Invalid Parameters. - 1",
            'files' => $_FILES 
        )));
    }

    // Check $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:

            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "No file sent. - 2",
                'files' => $_FILES
            )));

        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Exceeded filesize limit. - 3",
                'files' => $_FILES
            )));

        default:
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Unknown errors. - 4",
                'files' => $_FILES
            )));

    }

    // You should also check filesize here. 
    if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > 1000000) {
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Exceeded File Size Limit. - 5",
                'files' => $_FILES
            )));

    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['fileToUpload']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'status' => "Invalid file format. - 6",
            'files' => $_FILES
        )));

    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./gallery/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'status' => "Failed to move uploaded file. - 7",
            'files' => $_FILES
        )));

    }
        $filePathFull = sprintf('./gallery/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

        $uploaddir = '/gallery/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);


        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'status' => "File is uploaded successfully. - 8",
            'files' => $_FILES,
            'filePath' => $uploadfile
        )));
?>
```

I am trying to get the new file path which is `/gallery/` + the filename, however, I am getting an invalid JSON Object when I process it in my ExtJS part.

Can anyone help me with my problem? I also tried `sprintf('./gallery/%s.%s', sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Edit:

So far this works:

```
$uploaddir = '/gallery/';
$uploadFile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

die(json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'status' => "File is uploaded successfully. - 8",
    'filePath' => $uploadFile
)));
```

However, I don't have the file extension and I get something like: `/gallery/phptnLZJm` but upon checking, an image is actually uploaded but the filename is off.

Comment: Might be an issue with the slashes? Have you tried with urlencode($uploadFile) and then decoding it on the other side?

Comment: in the last block (die) what if you remove 'files'=>$_FILES .. and leave the rest, still get an invalid json object?

Comment: @JavierC.H., I tried `'filePath' => urlencode($uploadFile)` and removed  `'files'=>$_FILES`, but I still get an invalid JSON Object.

Comment: If you just return `json_encode(array(
            'success' => true))`, does that work?

Comment: Fixed the problem and updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work. I think it `sha1_file` was the issue. The code is now:

```
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./gallery/%s.%s',
            basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'status' => "Failed to move uploaded file. - 7",
            'files' => $_FILES
        )));

    }
//          $uploadFile = sprintf('./gallery/%s.%s',
//              sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

        $uploaddir = '/gallery/';
//          $uploadFile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        $name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];

        $fullPath = sprintf('/gallery/%s.%s',
            basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        );

        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'status' => "File is uploaded successfully. - 8",
            'filePath' => "$fullPath"
        )));
```

Before, I would call `sha1_file` instead of `basename` as I am assembling my `$fullPath`, and I don't know why. Was it because it was moved already and now has a different name?